# ruby add new key-value pair to nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Suppose we have a nested hash here.

```
a = {:"0" => {:CA => {:count => 10}}}
```

if we want to add a new hash pair to that hash, say

```
a = {:"0" => {:NY => {:count => 11}}}
```

and let it become

```
a = {:"0" => {:CA => {:count =>10}, :NY => {:count => 11}}}
```

what should I do?

I've tried

```
a[:0][:NY][:count] = 11
```

but get the error "undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: You may want to look at the formatting guide. use backticks for inline code like this `code here` or cariage return plus 4 spaces. Also looking at the preview helps a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you want to do something like this.

```
a = {:"0" => {:CA => {:count => 10}}}
b = {:"0" => {:NY => {:count => 11}}} 
a[:"0"][:NY] = b[:"0"][:NY] #=> {:"0"=>{:CA=>{:count=>10}, :NY=>{:count=>11}}}
```

You could also take advantage of merge

```
a = {:"0" => {:CA => {:count => 10}}}
b = {:"0" => {:NY => {:count => 11}}} 
a[:"0"] = a[:"0"].merge(b[:"0"]) #=> {:"0"=>{:CA=>{:count=>10}, :NY=>{:count=>11}}}
```

Answer (score 10):

You are getting the nil:NilClass error because you are trying to set a key of hash that doesn't exist yet. You need to create the hash that is the value of the key :NY.

```
a[:"0"].merge!({:NY => {:count => 11}})
```

or

```
a[:"0"][:NY] = {:count => 11}
```

Comment: How is this any different then what i said?

Comment: Before you're edit they were slightly different. Now the only difference is that my answer isn't creating an extra, and in my opinion, unnecessary hash before assigning or merging.